# ZeroMQ: how to implement client notifications?

Tags: networking, architecture, client-server, zeromq

So, there we've got a client-server interaction via ZMQ and have stucked into an architectural arguing about the proper pattern fitting our needs. I hope that someone wise and experienced may help resolve it.

It's not essential, but I need to mention that ZMQ is not being used directly, it's rather a Qt binding with C++ over the library itself, so low-level customizations are possible but undesirable (they would increase implementation efforts significantly).

### Current architecture

There was a need of some reliable, convenient & robust API broker, the one's been implemented via **REQ <-> REP**: statuses, error codes, encryption, etc. Encryption  's been implemented via separate authorization SSL channel, providing API with session keys, it's mentioned here to empasize that as far as SSL has not been provided at ZMQ's socket level (looked too complex), "session keys" exist (symmetric encryption key per client), it limits pattern solutions somehow.

So, there exist requests (client) + responses (server), it works. But we've recently met a need in *some notification mechanizm for clients*. Let's say the current broker API provides some types of data: X, Y, Z (lists of something). The client can get any of them but it has to be *notified when* any changes in X or Y or Z occur in order to know that new requests are to be done.

### The problem

Obviously, clients should receive either data updates or notifications that such updates exist. It could be a mere **PUB-SUB** problem, but it seems almost impossible to make this solution encrypted, or at least authorization-aware (not mentioning really "crutchy" ways to do it).

After some discussion two opinions appeared, describing two different workarounds:

1. Still use **PUB-SUB**, but only send notification type to the subscribers, like "hey, there's new X present". Clients-subscribers would have to perform already implemented API requests (**REP-REQ**) with session keys and all. Advantages: easy and working. Disadvantages: client logic complication.
2. Just rewrite API to use couples of **ZMQ_PAIR** sockets. Results in client-server behavior similar to plain sockets, but notifications can be "sent back" from server. Advantages: simple scheme. Disadvantages: rewriting, also broker won't differ much from a simple socket solution.

### Question

What would you adwise? Any of the descibed solutions or something better, maybe? Possibly X-Y problem exists here? Maybe something is considered a common way of solving problems like that?

Thanks in advance for any bright ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZMQ_PAIR socket are mainly used for communication between threads so I do not think they are a good solution for a client/server setup, if it all possible.

You could use ROUTER/DEALER instead of REQ/REP as they allow other patterns than just request/reply. I think newer version of ZeroMQ provide SERVER/CLIENT as a better alternative but I have not used them myself.

However, I would prefer a solution with a separate PUB/SUB channel because:

- You don't have to change the existing REQ/REP protocol.
- It allows only clients that are interested in notifications to connect to the PUB socket and process notifications. Other clients can use just the existing REQ/REP protocol.
- PUB/SUB can automatically send notification to multiple clients.
- PUB/SUB allows subscribing to specific notifications only.